# Flutter push notification using FCM by topic

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

hello I'm new to flutter and trying to get push notification in flutter , I have successfully subscribed the user to a topic and sent a notification through the firebase console by topic , what I'm trying to do is to have a button for admins in the app and when they post for a particular topic the users with that topic get the notification I have heard about cloud functions but I don't know exactly where to start ! i hope I made my point ! I have seen some videos that talks about  type script but is there is any workaround this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase documentation names [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) as an example use-case. From there:

> Developers can use Cloud Functions to keep users engaged and up to date with relevant information about an app. Consider, for example, an app that allows users to follow one another's activities in the app. Each time a user adds themselves as a follower of another user, a write occurs in the Realtime Database. Then this write event could trigger a function to create Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) notifications to let the appropriate users know that they have gained new followers.
> [image]
>
> 1. The function triggers on writes to the Realtime Database path where followers are stored.
> 2. The function composes a message to send via FCM.
> 3. FCM sends the notification message to the user's device.
>
> To review working code, see [Send FCM notifications](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).

Comment: ok but what should i do after coding my cloud function ?

Comment: Did you check the links? There's an example of a Cloud Function that calls FCM to send a message.